# MS Test randomly executes from Project Build Output path

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest

Whilst investigating an issue, whereby some unit tests were failing if using "Run All" from Test Explorer, I discovered that, if run in isolation or some other subset of all, they **succeeded** because they were **not being deployed** to a new test .\Out folder (as verified in the debug Modules window).

The issue of the failing tests turned out to be a missing assembly, *which I managed to resolve* but my question is: **why** are the tests *sometimes* run from my common build Output path (eg. ..\bin) and not *always* deployed to a clean TestResults....\Out location?

[nb. *I should add, the solution is **not** using a TestSettings file*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more searching, I found the answers in this Question: [how-to-set-the-working-directory-for-ms-test-projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543167/how-to-set-the-working-directory-for-ms-test-projects).

If "Run All" is chosen, the tests execute in one of the Deploy...\Out locations.

If a single test is chosen, the tests *will execute from the test project's own Output path*, if defined in the project's Properties\Build\Output path.