# "Unit" tests in visual studio failing when run together but succeed when run individually

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, telerik, telerik-open-access

I have written a bunch of repository methods against my database which I access using Telerik Data/Open Access ORM.  I have written about 30+ tests using "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting" tools. These are not "unit" tests in the strictest sense, but they exercise each individual repository method (please don't assault me with the definition of "unit" testing ... I know what it is and that I am not doing that).

Anyway, everything was going well, until ​this morning. As I usually do I ran all the tests just to make sure no gnomes changed my code while I slept. I was surprised to see that most of them failed ... but even more surprised to find the cause of their failure was the following error ...

***.Net SqlClient Data Provider :: Invalid column name 'voa_class'***

If you are familiar with Telerik OpenAccess ORM then you may be familiar with this error, if not, it deals with the presence (or lack of) of a discriminator column in a vertical inheritance model. "***voa_class***" is the column the ORM looks for when one is not specifically defined in the fluent description of the data model.

This error is confusing because ...

- This was working before
- Some of the tests that DID pass were also using the same classes using vertical inheritance, which in theory should also have failed.
- Both ends of the discriminator fields ARE being specifically defined in the Mapping/Description classes (using code-only approach)
- And most crazy of all .. when I run the test individually instead of running ALL the tests at the same time ... they pass!!

I can provide code and whatever if necessary. However, I don't feel it's specifically a code issue though since it was working before and the tests run successfully when run individually. I was hoping that someone may have seen and solved a similar issue and could share that solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Not that this is the issue but I have found at least this difference if run individually: [ms-test-randomly-executes-from-project-build-output-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231847/ms-test-randomly-executes-from-project-build-output-path)